# IllegalStateException when trying to return a JSON object from an Azure Mobile Services script

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, gson, azure-mobile-services

I have modified the update script for one of my tables in Azure Mobile Services to take in an object with an array of objects in it and use the MSSQL object to update the SQL records that pertain to those objects.That works fine, but I want my update script to return the updated list of objects back to the client. The problem is that I can't seem to return a JSON object back to the client and get that deserialized into a proper StoryList object without running into a "`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException`: `java.lang.IllegalStateException`" on the client.

I've spent hours trying to figure this out and still don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**: Here's the JSON that the client is choking on:

```
{"id":"arandomid",
 "stories":
[
{"id":"7EC413C3-17A8-410A-A394-ABF334364226",
"__createdAt":"2014-03-31T22:22:14.398Z",
"__updatedAt":"2014-04-28T01:43:27.484Z",
"__version":"AAAAAAAACf4=",
"title":"remove a user story",
"relativepriority":11,
"estimate":7,
"assignedto":"David",
"sprintid":"E51B4E0D-23C7-4695-BD9B-71E34A0BF5B5",
"sprintphase":1},

{"id":"99890AFE-13C2-4E1A-8376-B501CB07080D",
"__createdAt":"2014-03-31T22:26:35.160Z",
"__updatedAt":"2014-04-28T01:43:27.484Z",
"__version":"AAAAAAAACf0=",
"title":"view user story list",
"relativepriority":10,
"estimate":15,
"assignedto":"Michael",
"sprintid":"E51B4E0D-23C7-4695-BD9B-71E34A0BF5B5",
"sprintphase":1}
]
}
```

Here's the update script:

```
var storiesToUpdate;
var returnItem;
function update(item, user, request) {
    returnItem = item;
    storiesToUpdate = JSON.parse(item.stories);
    if(storiesToUpdate.length > 0){
       var sql = "UPDATE UserStory SET relativepriority = CASE id ";
       for(var i = 0; i < storiesToUpdate.length; ++i){
          sql+= ("WHEN '" + storiesToUpdate[i].id + "' THEN " + storiesToUpdate[i].relativepriority + " "); 
       }
       sql+="END ";
       sql+="WHERE ";
       for(var i = 0; i < storiesToUpdate.length; ++i){
          if(i > 0) sql+= "OR ";
          sql+= ("(id = '" + storiesToUpdate[i].id + "') "); 
       }

       mssql.query(sql,{
           success: function(connection){
                var sql2 = 'SELECT * from UserStory '
                sql2+="WHERE ";
                for(var i = 0; i < storiesToUpdate.length; ++i){
                   if(i > 0) sql2+= "OR ";
                   sql2+= ("(id = '" + storiesToUpdate[i].id + "') "); 
                }
                mssql.query(sql2,{
                    success:function(results){
                        console.log("results: " + results);
                        var returnObject = {};
                        returnObject["id"]="arandomid";
                        returnObject["stories"]=results;
                        console.log("return object: " + returnObject);
                        request.respond(statusCodes.OK, returnObject);
                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        console.log("Update ok, but subsequent read failed: " + err);
                        request.respond(err);
                    }
                });
           },
           error: function(err) {
               console.log("fail on open: " + err);
               request.respond(err);
           }
       });
    }
    else{
          request.respond();
        }
}
```

Here's the class being serialized/deserialized in the Android app:

```
public class StoryList {

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    private String mId;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("stories")
    ArrayList<UserStory> mStories;

    public StoryList(){

    }

    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public final void setId(String id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    public void setStories(ArrayList<UserStory> stories){
        this.mStories = stories;
    }

    public ArrayList<UserStory> getStories(){
        return mStories;
    }
}
```

And here's the CollectionSerializer class I've registered to enable sending up and hopefully getting back a collection of objects in a single query:

```
public class CollectionSerializer<E> implements
JsonSerializer<Collection<E>>, JsonDeserializer<Collection<E>>{

    public JsonElement serialize(Collection<E> collection, Type type,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonArray result = new JsonArray();
        for(E item : collection){
            result.add(context.serialize(item));
        }
        JsonPrimitive retVal = new JsonPrimitive(result.toString());
        Log.i("CollectionSerializer.Serialize", retVal.getAsString());
        return retVal;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Collection<E> deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
         Log.i("CollectionSerializer.Deserialize", element.getAsString());
         JsonArray items = (JsonArray) new JsonParser().parse(element.getAsString());
         ParameterizedType deserializationCollection = ((ParameterizedType) type);
         Type collectionItemType = deserializationCollection.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Collection<E> list = null;

        try {
            list = (Collection<E>)((Class<?>) deserializationCollection.getRawType()).newInstance();
            for(JsonElement e : items){
                list.add((E)context.deserialize(e, collectionItemType));
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Lastly, here's where I'm actually initiating the query to make the update:

```
@Override
public void onStoryListReorder(int phaseNumber){
    float newRelPriority = 10;
    ArrayList<UserStory> phaseStoryList = mPhaseStories.get(phaseNumber);

    for (UserStory s : phaseStoryList){
        s.setRelativePriority(newRelPriority++);
    }

    StoryList storylist = new StoryList();
    storylist.setStories(phaseStoryList);
    storylist.setId("blahblahblah");
    MobileServiceTable<StoryList> storyListTable = mClient.getTable("UserStory",StoryList.class);
    storyListTable.update(storylist, new TableOperationCallback<StoryList>(){
        public void onCompleted(StoryList entity,
                Exception exception, 
                ServiceFilterResponse response){
            if (exception == null){             
                //This is where I want to update the client's list of stories to match Azure's list.
            }
            else {
                createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error on updating: "+exception.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException This exception is raised when Gson attempts to read (or write) a malformed JSON element

Comment: Right, but what do I need to do differently in my script to make the JSON not be malformed?

Comment: Honestly ... you've posted a whole lot of code here ... and none of it really allows us to help you. Just glancing at it though it seems unlikely you'd need any sort of custom deserialization, and it seems like you're returning exactly one JSON object but are trying to treat it as a collection. Start by posting an example of the JSON being returned to your app.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to include the JSON itself :) I just added that. See my edit above. Regarding the CollectionSerializer, it's basically identical to what was suggested here as a way of sending up an ArrayList of objects: http://hashtagfail.com/post/44606137082/mobile-services-android-serialization-gson

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out. The problem was in my deserialize method for an ArrayList. The fixed deserialize method is as follows. The first line in the method fixed the issue:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<E> deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonArray items = element.getAsJsonArray();
    ParameterizedType deserializationCollection = ((ParameterizedType) type);
    Type collectionItemType = deserializationCollection.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    Collection<E> list = null;

    try {
        list = (Collection<E>)((Class<?>) deserializationCollection.getRawType()).newInstance();
        for(JsonElement e : items){
            list.add((E)context.deserialize(e, collectionItemType));
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Something to keep in mind in case anyone else is working off the example here: http://hashtagfail.com/post/44606137082/mobile-services-android-serialization-gson